# File handling in .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have developed an application using VB.NET, Visual Studio 2008 and the SQL Server database. Now I want to ignore the database (it has 1 table as customer (name,password,hour,minute)) as I don't want my client to install SQL Server separately or other overheads.

I am planning to do the whole using file handling in VB.NET (manipulating the data in files itself, for example change username, password, etc.). As I am new I don't actually know the proper way and of course need assistance.

Comment: Just a side note, but if you have a column in your Customer table called "password", **you're probably storing passwords incorrectly** ... See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what file format you'd like to use for your flat files, but one easy option is to use XML.  You can certainly generate your own format, but there's some easy tooling in VB.Net for reading and writing XML files.

To write an xml file:

```
Public Sub SaveAs(ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim writer As Xml.XmlWriter
    Dim settings As New Xml.XmlWriterSettings
    settings.Indent = True
    settings.CloseOutput = True
    writer = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings)

    writer.WriteStartElement("customer")

    writer.WriteStartElement("customerName")
    writer.WriteValue("customer #1")
    writer.WriteEndElement()

    writer.WriteEndElement()

    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

Reading from an XML document you can use some of the inline VB XML language features:

```
Public Sub Load(ByVal fileName as String)
    If Not IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then Throw New Exception("File not found.")
    Dim xDoc as XDocument

    Try 
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    Catch e as Xml.XmlException
        Throw New FileFormatException()
    End Try

    Dim customers = xDoc..<customer>
    For each customer in customers
        Dim customerName = customer.<customerName>.Value
        //'do something with the data
    Next

End Sub
```

Beth Massi has some [good videos on working with XML files and data in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb887653.aspx)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're new to the site, don't forget to accept one of the provided answers when you feel that it has answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use [SQLLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite), which is an in-process DB.  You could reuse most of your existing code and your client doesn't have to deal with the overhead of installing SQL Server.

Comment: Agree on Sql Server CE.  If you have already started down the Sql Server path, then the code should not change appreciably.  In addition, the Eneity Framework works with Sql CE.

Answer (score 1):

Some people prefer to store simple data as XML.  Then you can use LINQ or XPath to query the XML.
I have also seen others use a strongly-typed DataSet and persist it to the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do this using files... You will lose the bascic functionality provided by a db such as simple *INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/QUERY*

You could use a simple Database such as MS Access or [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

**Edit**

MS Access Connection string will depend on the version you are using, a little more detail on the possible version of Office/MS Access will help but

[MS Access 2007](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007):

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist
>   Security Info=False;

[Prior to MS Access 2007](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
>   Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User
>   Id=admin;Password=;

For Ms Access you need to use [OleDbConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(VS.71).aspx) instead of [SqlConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(VS.71).aspx) as for Sql Server

Comment: i am not aware of access. I tired to do that but has shown some error in provider name

Comment: Show us the error you received, and the version of MS Access, and we can try to help.

Comment: MS Access 2007, {"Keyword not supported: 'provider'."} is the error

and what is the replacement of thiscode in access
 Dim con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con = New SqlConnection(conn)

Comment: No, no. You do not want to recreate your project in MS Access, but purely use it as the database included in the project installer, so as to avoid Sql Server.

Comment: i didnot get the point i afraid, 
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\INDRANIL\Documents\GameOn.accdb
is my conn string

Comment: the whole thing is working fine with sql server. Now i onle change the connection string to , Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\INDRANIL\Documents\GameOn.accdb and now the error is Keyword not supported: 'provider'." (highlighting yellow on this line con = New SqlConnection(conn))

Comment: You cannot use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(VS.71).aspx to connect to Ms Acces,you need to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(VS.71).aspx

Comment: so u want me to replace all my sqlcommd with OleDbCommand?
Is there a way if i could talk to you? making my points more clearer?

Comment: Dim dr As SqlDataReader its in sql ...what is the oleDbCommand?

Comment: Have a look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I have not received anything yet, but will be taking it down. Please feel free to contact me here again if I do not respond X-)

Comment: sure i'll..Hey its working in access ..jus have a minor bug m looking through it...Could u help mewith deploying the application?

Comment: Yes, I will. Let me know what the issue is. Mailing me will be easier as we do not have to clog up the thread...