# Which database to use locally in a desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio

I have two different options using database in a desktop application. I prefer the *Service-based database* even locally. But should I use the *Local database* instead?

Comment: Depends which database system you can use. SQL Server or SQL Server CE.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 pro, and MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends of further requirements.

Server-Based: MS-SQL Express. Is essentially the same engine as larger editions, this will scale well when you need it bigger. Note that there is an attached-file mode that means you don't need to permanently register each database with the server.

Local: SQL Compact Editon, embedded file-based solution. Much easier to deploy but not 100% upward compatible. Basically a single-user solution (but that is going to change with v4)

Comment: Thanx for clearing this out. I'd expect something like this but never really knew exactly pros and cons of the different databases. BR -

Answer (score 6):

Best integrated in the .Net / VS enviroment is properly MS SQL Compact:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact

But there are alternative like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite

[Is there a .NET/C# wrapper for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite)

Comment: The SQLite for Android and Python I'm familiar with, but I didn't know there is one for .NET as well. Thanx for heads up! BR -

Answer (score 3):

Usually depends on where it'll be deployed. If you're deploying it in an environment that you control I'd usually go with a service-based, but if you need to send it out to clients it depends on the client. Clients with technical staff would probably want the service-based, but if it's a small client with no technical staff/knowledge that just want to click and run, then a local database might be best.

Comment: This is important stuff. Sometimes one want to send the app to a non-tech customer just showing capabilities. Your approach on the answer gives my insight I didn't have! BR -

Answer (score 3):

For a desktop application you should consider using Sqlite, with the C# wrapper library [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), I've been using it in a project and it works great, easy to use, quick and everything goes into a single file.

It's not designed for multiple user environment though, so you wouldn't want to use it as the database for a web service backend for instance.

I also use NHibernate and NHibernate.Linq to interact with the data, you can get a build of both which are compatible here: http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2009/07/nhibernate-210-ga-with-linq-and-fluent.html

Comment: I'm familiar with sqlite in Android and Python environments, but didn't know it worked on .NET as well. Thanx for making this clear for me. BR -

Comment: Also i use SQLITE db in my c# windows application and it's work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You must take a look at [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html)