# using MySQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to know if it is possible to use MySQL Engine without having to install WAMP Server. I'm developing an application that will require a database, so I was thinking of using MySQL instead of MS SQL or access. So I don't want to install the WAMP package yet I want to install the MySQL Engine, so if possible, please provide me with the download link for the MySQL and how to install and use (start/stop service).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need the [runtime](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and the [.net connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to make this happen. You also might find the [workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (gui tools to manage the server and run queries) to be helpful.

The runtime installs a service by default, which you can control on the commandline or via the windows service management console (services.msc).

Comment: Can I control the service through my C# application?

Comment: yup, you should be able to do that. you could do that using the command line commands detailed in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds to me a lot like you're thinking 'desktop application', where the MySQL database will be a simple local data store.  If that's the case, MySQL is not a good choice.

MySQL is a server-class database engine.  It's designed to run full time in the background as a service.  This makes it overkill for a simple desktop app, and as a user I'd be mad if your simple desktop app required me to run the MySQL service.

For the kind of app I think you're building, you really want an *in-process* or desktop-class database.  Good examples include SQLite, SQL Server Compact Edition (not Express), or even MS Access. Any of those would be a better option here than MySQL.

On the other hand, if I'm wrong and you're building a web app or an app that will be distributed to several computers that all share the same database, then MySQL is a perfectly fine choice and you should [read @Femaref's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779038/using-mysql-with-c/3779056#3779056).

Comment: +1 Good high level overview. Beat me to the post about SQLite and SQL Compact :-)

Comment: +1. Does the SQLite work with the C#? I`ve looked over the SQLite website and didn`t find anything concerning the C#!!

Comment: @sikas yes, sqlite works great with c#.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

If your database isn't going to be incredibly large you could go with `SQL Compact`.  It comes with the .NET framework, and works well for smaller databases.