# FunctionWithCollation unit test fails with System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I downloaded SqlLite 3.7.3 and [allegedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite) the best .NET wrapper for this database engine. I put them in the same directory and ran their provided test.exe.

Most tests succeeded, but two failed. FunctionWithCollation failed with SQLite error "no such function: CHARINDEX" and FunctionWithCollation2 failed with "The method or operation is not implemented".

The [support site](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) is silent and so is google. Does anybody have an idea what that means, and how if at all should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be very good to mention what are `FunctionWithCollation` and `FunctionWithCollation2` do so it would be easier to see what happens.

AFAIK sqlite3 does not support collation built-in as it is quite hard thing to do and allows you to plug in your own collation functionality: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html, AFAIK there are some ICU based collation providers.

So check this direction if it does not require you do add some plugin or so.

**EDIT:** From quick glance to the source code, the unit tests do some testing on charindex function. This function is extension, so:

- It seems a problem with either build or with the program or combination of them
- I don't think you should care unless you are using extensions. See: http://www.sqlite.org/contrib
- In any case I would suggest filling a bug.

Comment: I wish I would get a chance to know what these are. I certainly cannot. It's their database and their undocumented unit test.