# Portable C# Database

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sqlite

I am trying to make a portable (as in to run from a pen drive without and installation) C# application which will require a database.

My first thought was SQL, but I understand that SQL would require an SQL server installed. This cannot be guaranteed.

What is my best option here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite. See this question: [Is there a .NET/C# wrapper for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite) for easy integration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL CE or SQLLite, both are good.

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/07/08/SQLServerCE4SQLite.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQLite, make database and tables with SQLite Administrator - http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/, and put it in application folder.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Lite or MS SQL Compact, both are free.