# Do lightweight and no-install database systems exist?

Tags: c++, c, database

I would like to use the advatages of a database, instead of a flat file managed by myself. I would like to use QSL queries, etc, but without having a database management server as a separate install. I would like to have a program which I can release as a no-install, without requiring my end-user to install and configure mysql or WAMP or anything similar.

Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Have you checked out [SQLight](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Comment: can downvoter motivate? although simple, it seems to me a perfectly legitimate question!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia : I'm just waiting for the 10 minutes to pass so I can accept the answer. Prior to asking, I searched StackOverflow for this, and did not find anything useful. Does anyone think this question and its answer couldn't be useful for future visitors?

Comment: @vsz I guess you couldn't find anything useful on SO because this kind of questions is usually considered not constructive. Also questions and their answers tend to be outdated pretty fast and may be of little use for future vistors within 12 months.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238651/c-database-access-with-no-required-installation

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I didn't downvote, but perhaps it's the fact that both SQLite and a blog listing several alternatives are on the first page of Google hits for "lightweight and no-install database system."

Comment: @Filburt: although for this particular question, SQLite has been around for over 10 years, and I don't think it's going to disappear in the next 12 months. Let's not get ahead of ourselves by assuming that SO will outlive SQLite...

Comment: @SteveJessop I wouldn't predict SQLite to be that short-lived but usually questions require "the best" technology stack and the ORMs *du jour* around DBs are changing fast. On the whole I just tried to be more constructive than "Is Google not working for you?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try SQLite. It does not need a separate server instance yet you can write SQL queries.