# Create MDB File (Access DB) using .NET 7 in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-core, .net-7.0

I have a console application build on .NET Framework 4.7.

It converts raw data from binary files to MDB files.

I want to upgrade it to .NET 7.0 to support cross platforms.

I am able to convert all the code except for creating MDB files.

I am able to read the MDB files but I cannot create them.

I looked into Entity Framework Core but it isn't supporting my requirement.

Following is the code which is showing errors.

```
            //Create MDB file
            Catalog cat = new Catalog();
            cat.Create(constring);
            ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
            con.Close();
```

Comment: and what *is* the error you get?

Comment: Are you sure you want to migrate data *to* MDB files? Access is not a great database, there are stability, performance and size problems. Something like SQLite should work better for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: that's the problem, requirements demand that it should be MDB file only :( and my app would be cross platform if I find any work around for this

Answer (score 0):

Try working with [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/) NuGet package and [System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/7.0.0?_src=template) NuGet package.

Version of Access, consider using .accdb which the Jet package supports. Also, consider SQLite or SQL-Server as they are better choices than Access. Also, in regards to *cross platforms*, that is not possible with .mdb databases from what I know but could be incorrect.

The following creates a database with one table, adds two records then displays the data.

Note, use context.Database.EnsureCreated only if the database does not exists or you want to start over. See [Create and Drop APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created).

Console project using .NET Core 7

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere;

internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var context = new Context();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        Console.WriteLine("Database created");
        context.Add(new Category() { Name = "Breakfast food" });
        context.Add(new Category() { Name = "Produce" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        var categories = context.Categories.ToList();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{category.CategoryId,-3}{category.Name}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseJet(
                """
                Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;
                """);
        }
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;

}
```

Comment: worked like a charm but only in windows!!!

Comment: it still doesn't resolve my cross platform issue :(

Comment: I would expect .mdb not to be a good choice for cross platform see the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40616093/5509738) for an option which I have not used.