# how to create collection (1:n) relation

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm implementing SQLite database in my Windows Store application (WinRT).
I want to relation between two tables (1:n)
Book (1) - Chapter (n)

```
class Book
{
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Author { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

    public Book() 
    {
        this.Chapeters = new List<Chapter>();
    }
}
```

I get

```
-       $exception  {"Don't know about     System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Audioteka.Models.Chapter]"}    System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

+       [System.NotSupportedException]  {"Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Audioteka.Models.Chapter]"}    System.NotSupportedException

+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink    null    string
    HResult -2146233067 int
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
    Message "Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Audioteka.Models.Chapter]"  string
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there more to the error message? An exception, perhaps?

Comment: This additional information is message of the exception that I get

Comment: I've never seen an error message "Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1" before.  Are you sure you're copying and pasting the exact error message?

Comment: @Bobson I've updated my message and pasted more thata from exception after app breaks

Comment: I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki) that indicates that it supports relationships between tables at all.  That would lead me to believe that it only can understand basic value types which have a direct translation to SQL column types (int/long, float/double/decimal, string, etc).  So I can't help, and I can't point to anything that could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to follow up on my comment with a bit more research - SQLite-net doesn't support anything which can't be **directly** mapped to the database.  See [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/Features) for why:

> The ORM is able to take a .NET class definition and convert it to a SQL table definition. (Most ORMs go in the other direction.) It does this by examining all public properties of your classes and is assisted by attributes that you can use to specify column details.

You can look into using a different ORM to actually access your data (I use [Vici Coolstorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home)), if that's what you're trying to do, or simply remove the `List<Chapters>` from your class and add a `BookID` field to the `Chapters` class.  That's how the database would represent it.

For purposes of working with it, you could add one of these to your class:

```
List<Chapters> Chapters { 
  get { 
     return db.Query<Chapters> ("select * from Chapters where BookId = ?", this.Id); 
  } 
}
```

or

```
List<Chapters> Chapters { 
  get { 
     return db.Query<Chapters>.Where(b => b.BookId == this.Id); 
  } 
}
```

That would at least let you pull the list easily, although it would be slow because it hits the database every time you access it.

Comment: ok but I need the collection of chapters in my Book object :) I see that I should ignore chapters for ORM and populate it manualy while picking up the object. Hmm it's a big minus of SQLite :/

Comment: @Fixus - SQLite-net is probably not the ORM you want to be using.  It seems to be strictly for database creation and population, with query features being an afterthought.  SQLite itself doesn't have the issues, but you need a different way to communicate with it.

Comment: @Fixus - I also added a way to populate `Chapters`, although it's not a great way to handle it.

Comment: can you recomend some diffrent ways ? In every tutorial I've bumped on sqlite-net that is why I'm using it. Luck me that I can easly overcome this problem by little manual work so in THIS project this isn't very big problem but I would like to know better solution for the future. Thanks for the update

Comment: @Fixus - I use Vici Coolstorage (and I fixed the link to it in my answer), but I had some issues getting it set up.  I've heard good things about [Catnap](https://github.com/timscott/catnap), and there's always the various answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite).

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions). It provides complex relationships on top of SQLite-Net by using reflection.

Example extracted from the site:

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```