# C# SQlite Connection String Format

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

I have a 2 part question here:

1. I downloaded SQLite from [SQLite Website](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and for .NET 4.5 there was a "mixed" mode version and a "non-mixed mode" version.  How do I know which one I should use?

When making a connection I use the following command:

`>sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");`

2. The "Version=3" I assume represents the version of SQLite being used. If I download from the link above, the version says System.Data.SQLite 1.0.84.0 (3.7.15.2) package; should I change the Version=3 to Version=3.7.15.2 instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. You should pick the Mixed one.
2. the 1.0.84.0 is the newest version out for the `SQLite DLL`. I created
   an application with `SQLite` too in `c#`, my connection *string* looks
   like the following:

   ```
   sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\SQLITEDATABASES\SQLITEDB1.sqlite;Version=3;");
   ```

The version you are using, is `SQLite` version 3, the DLL is just a different version, but works with `SQLite` version 3.

Answer (score 11):

The following are different type of Sqlite Connection String

**Basic**

`Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;`

*Version 2 is not supported by this class library.*

**In-Memory Database**
An SQLite database is normally stored on disk but the database can also be stored in memory.

`Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;`

**Using UTF16**

`Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;UseUTF16Encoding=True;`

**With password**

`Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myPassword;`

Answer (score 5):

SQLite is written in C. For Windows, it is distributed as a compiled 32 bit (x86) .dll. This cannot be used from .NET directly because it is native code and .NET programs don't normally like to interact with native code. It can be done with something called COM Interop, but in my hands that is not easy or pretty.

In your question you reference a download page that is for System.Data.SQLite. This is a slightly different implementation than plain old SQLite. It takes C SQLite and wraps it with .NET code - allowing use of the C native code by .NET programs (hooray, someone else did the work).

When you have both native code (the C SQLite) and .NET code (the wrapper functions) together in one assembly, that is called a mixed-mode assembly, and originally it made sense to put everything in one file. If you are doing development or only using SQLite on your own machine, then using a mixed-mode assembly is fine.

However, things have changed with 64 bit Windows IF you want to distribute your application to customers. This is because mixed-mode assemblies can only run on the architecture they were compiled for (a white lie, but true for this answer). As of version 1.0.80.0 of System.Data.SQLite, it is strongly suggested you distribute:
1.) The all .NET .dll System.Data.SQLite.dll, which can run on 32 bit or 64 bit architectures)
AND
2.) a 32-bit .dll x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
AND
3. a 64 bit .dll x64\SQLite.Interop.dll

The all .NET wrapper (item 1) figures out which which architecture it is running on and picks the 32 bit or 64 bit .dll accordingly.

All this is described on the System.Data.SQLite downloads page that you referenced, but I found it confusing so I offer my summary.

The version discrepancy you note in your question is also due to the difference between SQLite and System.Data.SQLite.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite?rq=1)

Comment: System.Data.SQLite also is a ADO.NET implementation but I didn't mention that aspect because it's not related to your question. See [C# wrapper for SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite?rq=1)