# I pass a path to my SQliteConnection but my application can't find it

Tags: c#, sqlite

I pass a  filename to my connection :

[image]

2 screenshots of the path :

[image]

[image]

My app went in breakmode giving following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl, Version=2.0.3.851,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b68184102cba0b3b' or one of its
> dependencies.'

So it can't find the file I'm passing to the connection.

[the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cNsw.png)

Comment: Hello, it is nice you are listing the error, but it would help if you could show the code. Specially the connection string. Do you have read-access to the file where your SQLite database resides? Is your specification accurate?

Comment: The code of the connection string is the first screenshot. and yes I do have access

Comment: Take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726265/c-sharp-sqlite-connection-string-format

Comment: This site prefers code to be posted as text, not images.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work: 
        static string file = @"Data Source=C:\Users\jamie\source\repos\EindwerkMobile\MobileEindwerk\MobileEindwerk\DataBase\DataBaseEindwerk.db;Version=3;";

Comment: Use the edit link under your question.

Comment: what do you mean Lars

Comment: Correct.  Don't put your code in comments.  Edit your question with the code by using the edit link under your question.  Also, any chance the folder is "jamie van gossum" and not "jamie"?

Comment: I changed the path and tried to start the application and it goes in break mode again = it doesn't work

Comment: Lars and NoChance I added a link to an image of the path, its jamie and not Jamie Van Gossum

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong, before folder "source" we see in the picture folder name "jamie Van Gossum" not "jamie".

try this :

```
C:\Users\jamie Van Gossum\source\repos\EindwerkMobile\MobileEindwerk\MobileEindwerk
\DataBase\DataBaseEindwerk.db
```