# Move database from Django Project (sqlite) to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, python, django, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I started a project using django & python, but have since decided that it will be done in Visual Studio 2010 using c#. Im a newbie when it comes to all of these by the way.

I followed a load of tutorials to get some stuff going in django, including creating a database and adding a fair amount of info to it.

Now i would like to 'transfer' this database from django on one system to vs2010 on a different system.

Is there anyway i can do this? what would be the best?

The django database was created in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about visual studio, and you aren't saying what the "other" sytem. So, for the question:

> Is there anyway i can do this? what would be the best?

Are you thinking we can answer a question like that?

Well, what i can say is that you can get the database in json format using [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) and then in visual studio read that info and save into new db.

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp > myfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to what [@Darwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948416/darwin) says there is not necessarily any need to recreate the database. If you are happy with the schema you can just copy the SQLite database into your working directory in visual studio and connect to it using your chosen database access class. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite) for information on C# wrappers.

Comment: would that just be a case of moving the data.db file into the App_Data folder or my MVC project?

Comment: You have to put the DB in the directory that your executable is run from. That way you know the path to pass to your DB access class.