# using MySQL without installing server

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to use MySQL without install? I am making an desktop application using Visual Studio and C#  that uses MySQL. I will use this program on another computer.if this computer has no MySQL installation my program will also work? Can I move my database with my application?

Comment: instead of mysql, you can use sqlite as it is mostly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... You will need the computer to have mysql and your compiled code. What you CUD do if your database is not too big is hardcode the data storage and retrieval in your code itself.. in that case you wont need mysql installed there..
OR you cud allow network access to mysql on another machine(server) in that case u only need mysql on the server

Comment: is there no way to use like Microsoft office Access file?

Comment: If you mean, can you use MySQL like Access where the database is just a file on your machine that you can move from computer to computer without the application, no.

Comment: there is possibility to connect to server somewhere in internet too.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need the server installed locally. You do need some sort of client, though. For C, you would need the `mysqlclient` library. I assume C# has something similar to enable the CLR to talk to MySQL.

If you are looking for a portable database, check out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). As for the best library for C#, see these answers:

- [What is the best way to connect and use a sqlite database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-and-use-a-sqlite-database-from-c)
- [Is there a .NET/C# wrapper for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite)

Comment: doest the mysqlclient library communicate to a mysql server? So you DO need a server just not locally

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to use MySQL, there has to be a server running /somewhere/. However, it seems you want something portable, so I have updated my answer accordingly.