# How can I read the content of a SQLite database in Windows OS programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, sqlite

I have copied the db file of my android app to my desktop pc. There are some windows applications that read the content of SQLite files like "SQLite Database Browser". Now I want to read the content of db files in my own windows application using C# or C++ languages similarly. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: No need to add the android tag. this is not android specific question. Android SQLite database is just ordinary SQLite database. I am removing the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to access your SQLite database in C# should be in the answers there:

[What is the best way to connect and use a sqlite database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-and-use-a-sqlite-database-from-c-sharp)

And the question also mentions the library for C++ (sqlite.h)