# How to Connect From WindowsApplication Sqlite Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, host

I have a Windows Application written in C#, using Sqlite3 as its database. I want to update my database in **Host** with my Windows Application database.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an SQLite3 database using the following code.

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=/path/to/file.db;Version=3;");
db.Open();
```

If you want to specify additional connection parameters, [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sqlite) is always a good resource. Also, you might check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-and-use-a-sqlite-database-from-c-sharp) which is similar to yours.

Comment: i want to send data to database in host;

Comment: i think first must create a certificate file or authorization by host.then i can connect to Database in Host;

Comment: SQLite is an embedded only database system which means that you must access it as if it were a local resource. If the database exists on the same machine your application will run from, then just simply specify the path and filename to the SQLite database. If the database exists on a remote system, then you will need some sort of file-sharing process. On Windows, you can set up a file share on the remote system and then map a drive to it on the local system.