# Webkit.NET set Local Storage data?

Tags: c#, local-storage, whatsapp, webkit.net

I am using WebKit.NET to simulate a WhatsApp-Bot. I have looked for the required LocalStorage files and loaded the WhatsApp connection data into my C# Application.

My local storage is currently a `Directory<string, string>` containing the relevant data, but I am unable to somehow transfer this data to my [`Webkit-WebkitBrowser`](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet)-instance.

Does someone have an idea, how I could set the WebkitBrowser local storage?

---

**Addendum №1:** I used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-and-use-a-sqlite-database-from-c-sharp) snippet to access my Google Chrome local storage files (which are SQLite-databases located in `%LocalAppData%/Google/Chrome/UserData/Default/Local Stroage/....`)

---

**Edit №2:** I tried using the Property `Webkit::WebkitBrowser.LocalStorageDatabaseDirectory` and setting it to the directory, in which the local storage files are residing - but it did not load the local storage ...

Comment: Are you looking to use the WhatApp local storage in your application? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, Sir. My intention is/was to import the local storage from my regular Webbroswer (Google Chrome) into my C# application. The reading itself worked fine ... my only problem is now to import the data into my `Webkit.WebkitBroswer`-instance..... Could you please specify or elaborate, why you are thinking that this operation is not possible?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I thought that local storage was isolated on a per user/per application level. However, if you can already read the data then I'm clearly mistaken.